# How to test tr(table row) has onclick and style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} in react testing library

Tags: enzyme, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, react-testing

```
<tbody data-testid="offers-list-tablebody">
            { offers.map((Offer) => (
              <tr onClick={this.handleTermsAndConditionsBtnClick} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} key={index}>
}
```

I tried in this way

```
 const tableBody = list.find("[data-testid='offers-list-tablebody']");

    const tableRow1 = tableBody.childAt(0);

    const clickElement1 = (tableRow1.key());
    expect(clickElement1.onclick).toBeTruthy();
    expect(clickElement1).toHaveStyle("cursor: pointer");
```

The error is Property "onclick does not exist on type string" and it is hsowing value of index when tested.
How to test this?

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, reproducible code example

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are assigning `clickElement1` to `tableRow1.key()` which returns a string.

Replace `clickElement` with `tableRow1` like below

```
    expect(tableRow1.onclick).toBeTruthy();
```